Compact group with a finite fundamental group "built" from a connected, simply connected group and a finite group
I am reading the Dijkgraaf-Witten paper on the classification of TQFT. In the first part, the authors considered two opposite types of gauge group. The first type is a connected and simply-connected compact Lie group, and the second type is a finite group. They showed that both types of TQFTs are classified by $H^4(BG,\mathbb{Z})$. They moved on to argue that TQFTs with an arbitrary compact Lie group is also classified by $H^4(BG,\mathbb{Z})$.
One justification they gave was that "general Lie groups can be built in simply ways from the types [of groups] considered above". To this end, they showed two exact sequences. First, they gave $1\to G_0\to G\to \Gamma\to 1$, and then $1\to \pi_1(G)\to\tilde G \to G \to 1$, in which $\Gamma$ is finite and $\tilde G$ is the simply connected universal cover of $G$. Then they said by "combining these two sequences, any compact $G$ with finite fundamental group is built from a connected, simply connected group and some finite groups".
The quoted text confuses me, maybe because I am not fluent in the mathematical language. My specific questions are:
(1) what do they mean by "combining" these two exact sequences?
(2) How exactly do they "build" the compact group $G$?

The use of the words "combining" and "build" here are both informal, at least as far as I know. Generally, if we have a short exact sequence
$$1 \to K \to G \to H \to 1$$
then we say that this sequence exhibits $G$ as an extension of $H$ by $K$ (sometimes people put $H$ and $K$ in the opposite order here). It's common to think of such a sequence as "building $G$ out of $K$ and $H$" (and some auxiliary data). Roughly, $G$ is a kind of "twisted product" of $K$ and $H$; this is easiest to see in the case that the above sequence splits on the right, in which case $G$ is a semidirect product $K \rtimes H$ (so the auxiliary data is an action of $H$ on $K$). In general there is a cohomological classification of extensions in terms of data involving $K$ and $H$.
We can iterate this process, and say that if $G$ has been "built" out of $K$ and $H$ in the above sense, then we can go further and "build" another group from $G$ by placing it in another short exact sequence as above. In the case of Lie groups, the canonical sequence
$$1 \to G_0 \to G \to \pi_0(G) \to 1$$
"builds a Lie group $G$ from a connected Lie group $G_0$ and a discrete group $\pi_0(G)$" (both of which are compact if $G$ is). We actually need to interpret the second sequence
$$1 \to \pi_1(G) \to \widetilde{G_0} \to G_0 \to 1$$
differently; in this context the connected group $G_0$ is the one we want to "build," and this sequence simply tells us that $G_0$ is the quotient of a simply connected Lie group $\widetilde{G_0}$ by a discrete normal (in fact central) subgroup $\pi_1(G)$. So in this case the meaning of "build" can be made precise, it means taking a quotient.
Informally these two short exact sequences "build a Lie group $G$ out of the discrete group $\pi_0(G)$, the discrete group $\pi_1(G)$, and the simply connected Lie group $\widetilde{G_0}$." This is how we reduce the classification of Lie groups to the classification of simply connected Lie groups, which is in turn equivalent to the classification of (f.d.) Lie algebras. See e.g. this MO thread.

A typical example here is $G = O(n)$, the orthogonal group. The first short exact sequence for this group is
$$1 \to SO(n) \to O(n) \xrightarrow{\det} \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 1$$
and it "builds $O(n)$ out of $SO(n)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$." This one happens to be split so here we can be precise about what "build" means: it means that $O(n)$ is a semidirect product
$$O(n) \cong SO(n) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$$
where the action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ can be given by conjugation by any reflection. Next, for $n \ge 3$ the universal cover of $SO(n)$ is the spin group $\text{Spin}(n)$, and the corresponding short exact sequence is
$$1 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \text{Spin}(n) \to SO(n) \to 1$$
which "builds $SO(n)$ out of $\text{Spin}(n)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$." Again, here this just means taking the quotient. Altogether, this pair of short exact sequences "builds $O(n)$ out of $\pi_0(O(n)) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2, \pi_1(O(n)) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, and $\text{Spin}(n)$" in the sense that
$$O(n) \cong (\text{Spin}(n)/\mathbb{Z}_2) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2.$$

Thanks for the clear answer! There is no way I could have figured that the second short exact sequence should be interpreted as that involving $G_0$, the connected subgroup of $G$. I like the example you gave. Going back to their paper, interestingly the prescription they gave seems to not work for $G=U(1)$, as its fundamental group is not finite.

@pathintegral: yes, that's right. That part of the introduction is just a heuristic argument anyway. The story I sketched out above is sort of standard mathematical lore, it's how you reduce the classification of Lie groups to the classification of Lie algebras (since this corresponds exactly to the classification of simply connected Lie groups).
